# reuse directory index instead of rebuilding on lucene.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, lucene.net, lucene

I'm using lucene.net for a search on huge file, the search is amazing fast and I'm really happy with it. We are using Lucene.Net.Store.Directory to store the index and we build the index in the global.asax app_start.

**What I'm missing** is if **there is a way to avoid rebuilding if the index is already written to the directory**, since the data are very static and **we would like to avoid rebuilding the index** until we really need to explicitly update tha data.

**Reusing the already built and written index is possible in lucene.net.. somehow?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that you're using a `RAMDirectory` to store the file? Or a `FSDirectory`?

If you're using a `RAMDirectory`, switch to `FSDirectory` to persist your index between application recycles.

Use `IndexReader.LastModified(Directory)` to determine if you're content is outdated and you need an index rebuild.

Comment: I am using FSDirectory but i always need to rebuild index after pool recycle (in a web application). I am using singleton to retain the FSDirectory but when the application restart I create a new FSDirectory pointing to the same index directory but the last index is lost. @gaddoz how did you solve this?

Comment: @robsonrosa, what you describes would occur if you never commit your IndexWriter, or passing `true` to the create-parameter in the constructor of IndexWriter when opening a new one.

Comment: @SimonSvensson, it was exacty what you said: i was passing true to create-parameter of IndexWriter. Fixing it, the problem was solved! thanks